# for f in do command, but looking in subdirectoreis (OSX terminal)

Tags: macos, for-loop, terminal, rename, subdirectory

I have found this command but am not finding a way to make it remove the `.bts` extension off of files within subdirectories.

The problem is this program bittorrent sync had a major bug and added `.bts` to all the filenames on a folder of my NAS. The files are there but not readable until the extension is removed.

I have managed to use this withing a directory:

```
for f in *.bts; do mv "$f" "${f%.*}"; done
```

Though know nothing about the command line/terminal in osx or anywhere... I read I could use

```
for /r in %%G
```

but that's not working. Anybody know a fix?

Comment: Do you use `homebrew`?

Comment: Where is your NAS mounted? Can you start `Terminal` and run `ls /Volumes` and paste the results?